# Dynamic row reference VBA

Tags: vba

I'm stuck on a problem and would appreciate any help. The code below applies a formula to a cell based on a condition. However, the cell reference for the XLOOKUP needs to be dynamic in the sense that it references the row where the condition is met (C9, C21 etc). The column is constant. Currently the ActiveCell.Row only references wherever the user has clicked.
Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you

```
Sub CopyC()

    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Set SrchRng = Range("F1:F1000")


    For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(cel.Value, "PIPE") > 0 Then
    
    cel.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=XLOOKUP(" & Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Address & ",PRODUCTION_ORDER[ARTICLE_NO],PRODUCTION_ORDER[BATCH])"
    
End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("C" & Cel.Row)` ?

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much!